# How can I enable the button where I am of the steps component in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Few weeks ago I start my intership with a new company and they are working with **Primefaces** to use **Java EE**. I do not know too much about Java or Primefaces, so I am a bit lost (as with my english).

They ask me to make a **step component**, but the component do not work as they want. They need that the component do not disable the button where you are when you click on the next step, I mean, if you are in step 4th, they want to let it enable, even if you go backwards.

I try to make it works changing the readonly attribute to false, use some JavaScript with some variables to enable the links (but that make my proyect crash), use a varible of Java EE that I use to change the color of the .ui-step-number but does not work with the link...

```html
<p:steps widgetVar="steps" id="steps" readonly="false" activeIndex="#{actemplate.seccionRenovacion}" style="border: none; height: auto; width: 100%; font-weight: bold;">                                                                
    <p:menuitem id="menu_step1" class="menuItemRenewal" value="#{texto['ac_menu_step1']}" style="color:  #{actemplate.pasoRenovacion gt 1 ? 'green;' : ''}"/>
    <p:menuitem id="menu_step2" class="menuItemRenewal" value="#{texto['ac_menu_step2']}" outcome="tratamientos" style="color:  #{actemplate.pasoRenovacion gt 2 ? 'green;' : ''}"/>                                    
    <p:menuitem id="menu_step3" class="menuItemRenewal" value="#{texto['ac_menu_step3']}" outcome="personal" style="color:  #{actemplate.pasoRenovacion gt 3 ? 'green;' : ''}"/>
    <p:menuitem id="menu_step4" class="menuItemRenewal" value="#{texto['ac_menu_step4']}" outcome="encargados" style="color:  #{actemplate.pasoRenovacion gt 4 ? 'green;' : ''}"/>
    <p:menuitem id="menu_step5" class="menuItemRenewal" value="#{texto['ac_menu_step5']}" outcome="sitios_web" style="color:  #{actemplate.pasoRenovacion gt 5 ? 'green;' : ''}"/>                                         
</p:steps>
```

---

When you go to the next step, you can click on the steps before, but when your page change, you can not go directly to the page that you were working (if you are in page 3 and go to page 1, you can not go again to page 3 directly, you need to make the step before again).

Comment: maybe you can find your answere here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45626939/psteps-but-enable-click-on-all-steps

Comment: Or maybe you'll feel more comfortable at [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions).

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution but using **JavaScript**, I do not know how to make it works with JAVA, but I will post it here, so if anyone else have the same problem, I hope it will work for your code also.

```
<script>        
  var item1 = document.getElementById("menuform:menu_step1");
  var item2 = document.getElementById("menuform:menu_step2");
  var item3 = document.getElementById("menuform:menu_step3");
  var item4 = document.getElementById("menuform:menu_step4");
  var item5 = document.getElementById("menuform:menu_step5");

  // Step 1
  if(#{actemplate.pasoRenovacion} >= 1){
    item1.setAttribute("href", "mi_entidad.xhtml");
    item1.setAttribute("onclick", true);
    item1.style.cursor = "pointer";

    // Step 2
    if(#{actemplate.pasoRenovacion} >= 2){
      item2.setAttribute("href", "tratamientos.xhtml");
      item2.setAttribute("onclick", true);
      item2.style.cursor = "pointer";

      // Step 3
      if(#{actemplate.pasoRenovacion} >= 3){
        item3.setAttribute("href", "personal.xhtml");
        item3.setAttribute("onclick", true);
        item3.style.cursor = "pointer";

        // Step 4
        if(#{actemplate.pasoRenovacion} >= 4){
          item4.setAttribute("href", "encargados.xhtml");
          item4.setAttribute("onclick", true);
          item4.style.cursor = "pointer";

          // Step 5
          if(#{actemplate.pasoRenovacion} >= 5){
            item5.setAttribute("href", "sitios_web.xhtml");
            item5.setAttribute("onclick", true);
            item5.style.cursor = "pointer";          
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

So first of all, I make a **variable** with all the elements of the object '*steps*'. It must also works with **JQuery**, but the company do not have it implemented, so I work with the **DOM**.

After that, I capture a **JAVA variable** from the **bean**, that will be added one-by-one when you pass to the next step. Since we have that, you can make a simple 'if' (I use it nested).

Finally, you can set the attributes that you want to the element. I set the href and the click event (**that two are importants**, because the 'steps' elements change the **href to #**, and the **click event to false**, when you do not pass the step, with that changes you can now click on the step that you are at the moment, or came again if you go to step previous steps), and give style to the cursor, to looks like you are over a link.