# How to properly report an error to client through WebSockets

Tags: java, java-websocket, javax

How do I properly close a websocket and and provide a clean, informative response to the client when an internal error occurs on my server? In my current case, the client must provide a parameter when it connects, and I am trying to handle incorrect or missing parameters received by OnOpen.

[This example](https://github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/websocket-exception-handling/blob/master/src/main/java/martinandersson/com/websockets/MyServerEndpoint.java) suggests I can just throw an exception in OnOpen, which will ultimately call OnError where I can close with a reason and message. It kinda works, but the client only receives an EOF, 1006, CLOSE_ABNORMAL.

Also, because I have found no other discussion, I can't tell what might be best practice.

I'm using the JSR-356 spec, as follows:

```
@ClientEndpoint
@ServerEndpoint(value="/ws/events/")
public class WebSocketEvents
{
    private javax.websocket.Session session;
    private long token;

    @OnOpen
    public void onWebSocketConnect(javax.websocket.Session session) throws BadRequestException
    {
        logger.info("WebSocket connection attempt: " + session);
        this.session = session;
        // this throws BadRequestException if null or invalid long
        // with short detail message, e.g., "Missing parameter: token"
        token = HTTP.getRequiredLongParameter(session, "token");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onWebSocketText(String message)
    {
        logger.info("Received text message: " + message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onWebSocketClose(CloseReason reason)
    {
        logger.info("WebSocket Closed: " + reason);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onWebSocketError(Throwable t)
    {
        logger.info("WebSocket Error: ");

        logger.debug(t, t);
        if (!session.isOpen())
        {
            logger.info("Throwable in closed websocket:" + t, t);
            return;
        }

        CloseCode reason = t instanceof BadRequestException ? CloseReason.CloseCodes.PROTOCOL_ERROR : CloseReason.CloseCodes.UNEXPECTED_CONDITION;
        try
        {
            session.close(new CloseReason(reason, t.getMessage()));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            logger.warn(e, e);
        }

    }
}
```

**Edit:** The exception throwing per linked example seems weird, so now I am catching exception within OnOpen and immediately doing

```
session.close(new CloseReason(CloseReason.CloseCodes.CANNOT_ACCEPT, "some text"));
```

**Edit:** This turned out to be correct, though a separate bug disguised it for a while.

---

**Edit2**: Clarification: `HTTP` is my own static utility class. `HTTP.getRequiredLongParameter()` gets query parameters from the client's initial request by using

```
session.getRequestParameterMap().get(name)
```

and does further processing.

Comment: Is it possible that throwing an exception in `OnOpen` is closing the session before `OnError` is called? Are you seeing `"Throwable in closed websocket"` being logged?

Comment: @Remy Nope, "throwable in closed..." is not logged.

Comment: Edited with new info. It is _functionally_ acceptable as-is. But what I'm really seeking is the "best practice" answer that is helpful to my server's clients, and may be nothing like what I'm doing.

Comment: Have you considered putting a filter ahead? Unrelated question but why your class is annotated with `ServerEndpoint` and `ClientEndpoint` at the same time? If you don't want to use a filter, you can also consider a custom configuration where you'll check if the parameter is here or not and what value it has

Comment: @ASE I know little about filters. I think I have a good answer, though (see answer). `ClientEndpoint` was combined with `ServerEndpoint` in the first example I found. Thanks for pointing out; removed now.

Comment: @Remy I now believe you had the answer. It was obscured because OnError wasn't even entered. If you make an Answer, I'll pick it.

Comment: @Saturn5 I was kind of lazy to find relevant link so I posted an answer which can give you some food for thought. It may not directly help for this problem but it definitively helped me a lot for my websocket design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I should have placed...

```
session.close(new CloseReason(CloseReason.CloseCodes.CANNOT_ACCEPT, "some text"));
```

...right where the error occurs, within @OnOpen(). (For generic errors, use `CloseCodes.UNEXPECTED_CONDITION`.)

The client receives:

```
onClose(1003, some text)
```

This is, of course, the obvious answer. I think I was misled, by the example cited, into throwing an exception from @OnOpen(). As **Remy Lebeau** suggested, the socket was probably closed by this, blocking any further handling by me in @OnError(). (Some other bug may have obscured the evidence that was discussed.)

Comment: the onError is triggered on exception. As Remy Lebeau suggested, if an exception is thrown anywhere, in your particular case during `@OnOpen`, then `@OnError` is called. If you wish to close the connection during @OnOpen without having an exception thrown, I guess your best bet is to put a try/catch and close the connection in your catch

Answer (score 2):

To develop the points I mentioned, your problem about "how to handle a required parameter", I can see following options. First of all, let's consider the endpoint:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/myendpoint", 
                configuration = MyWebsocketConfiguration.class)
public class MyEndpoint{
    // @OnOpen, @OnClose, @OnMessage, @OnError...
}
```

### Filtering

The first contact between a client and a server is a HTTP request. You can filter it with a filter to prevent the websocket handshake from happening. A filter can either block a request or let it through:

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;

public class MyEndpointFilter implements Filter{
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // nothing for this example
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // if the connection URL is /websocket/myendpoint?parameter=value
        // feel free to dig in what you can get from ServletRequest
        String myToken = request.getParameter("token");

        // if the parameter is mandatory
        if (myToken == null){
            // you can return an HTTP error code like:
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }

        // if the parameter must match an expected value
        if (!isValid(myToken)){
            // process the error like above, you can
            // use the 403 HTTP status code for instance
            return;
        }

        // this part is very important: the filter allows
        // the request to keep going: all green and good to go!
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //nothing for this example
    }

    private boolean isValid(String token){
         // how your token is checked? put it here
    }
}
```

If you are using a filter, you must add it in your web.xml:

```
<web-app ...>

    <!-- you declare the filter here -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>myWebsocketFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.mypackage.MyEndpointFilter </filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <!-- then you map your filter to an url pattern. In websocket
         case, it must match the serverendpoint value -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>myWebsocketFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/websocket/myendpoint</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

the `async-supported` was suggested [by BalusC in my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664640/4906586) to support asynchronous message sending.

**TL,DR**

if you need to manipulate GET parameters provided by the client at the connection time, Filter can be a solution if you are satisfied with a pure HTTP answer (403 status code and so on)

### Configurator

As you may have noticed, I have added `configuration = MyWebsocketConfiguration.class`. Such class looks like:

```
public class MyWebsocketConfigurationextends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {

    // as the name suggests, we operate here at the handshake level
    // so we can start talking in websocket vocabulary
    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig sec, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {

        // much like ServletRequest, the HandshakeRequest contains
        // all the information provided by the client at connection time
        // a common usage is:
        Map<String, List<String>> parameters = request.getParameterMap();

        // this is not a Map<String, String> to handle situation like
        // URL = /websocket/myendpoint?token=value1&token=value2
        // then the key "token" is bound to the list {"value1", "value2"}
        sec.getUserProperties().put("myFetchedToken", parameters.get("token"));
    }
}
```

Okay, great, how is this different from a filter? The big difference is that you're adding here some information in the user properties during the handshake. That means that the `@OnOpen` can have access to this information:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/myendpoint", 
                configuration = MyWebsocketConfiguration.class)
public class MyEndpoint{

     // you can fetch the information added during the
     // handshake via the EndpointConfig
     @OnOpen
     public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config){
         List<String> token = (List<String>) config.getUserProperties().get("myFetchedToken");

         // now you can manipulate the token:
         if(token.isEmpty()){
             // for example: 
             session.close(new CloseReasons(CloseReason.CloseCodes.CANNOT_ACCEPT, "the token is mandatory!");
         }
     }

    // @OnClose, @OnMessage, @OnError...
}
```

**TL;DR**

You want to manipulate some parameters but process the possible error in a websocket way? Create your own configuration.

### Try/catch

I also mentioned the try/catch option:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/myendpoint")
public class MyEndpoint{

     @OnOpen
     public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config){

         // by catching the exception and handling yourself
         // here, the @OnError will never be called. 
         try{
             Long token = HTTP.getRequiredLongParameter(session, "token");
             // process your token
         }
         catch(BadRequestException e){
             // as you suggested:
             session.close(new CloseReason(CloseReason.CloseCodes.CANNOT_ACCEPT, "some text"));
         }
     }

    // @OnClose, @OnMessage, @OnError...
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: I don't really know the etiquette of SO but I guess you should rather append your edit to your post. Btw, your edit contains very important information :)