# a filter or servlet of the current chain does not support asynchronous operations

Tags: java, netbeans, jersey

I have added **reader interceptor** to decode the gzip compressed request body, i converted the **jersey** restful service method to asynchronous supported , after that i am getting this error while making a request.i am using netbeans to develop this jersey service.

Comment: In you're using Java EE, can you try adding `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` in your `filter?` like how [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664640/4906586) suggests?

Comment: Hi AI1 there is no web.xml file in this project, i am using netbeans , can you tell me where to add this setting?

Comment: As you're using Jersey, I assume you have a Java EE project, isn't it. How do you register filter? Rather, can you provide more information regarding the faulty filter?

Comment: yes i am using Jersey. i didn't manually register , i think the @Provider annotation will take care that. the filter is working perfectly if the web method is not asynchronous.